# How should I indicate a long request to the user in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest

I have an rails application with a huge database (hundreds of gigabytes) that has a lot of different options what to do with the data. In some cases, like changing data, this can be done in a background task I do with Sidekiq. But in other cases, like viewing data with a lot of rows and columns or complex SQL queries, the process of getting the data takes quite long.

What I want to do, is show the user that something is happening when he clicks a link. Like the progress bar many browsers have, but more obvious, so even users not used to working with browsers should see that something is happening and loading.

The question is how to do this. I already tried different options with AJAX and jQuery but most of the times I can only do this for certain actions, but basically I want to do it for the whole application. So every time the user sends a request to load a new page, I want to immediately show him, that something is happening.

The closest I came was a Javascript, that was always triggered. The problem was that it literally happened every time and forced to reload the page. This means when I toggled an element it showed the progress bar and then reloaded the page.

**In essence, what I'm looking for:**

My application runs on Ruby and Rails 4 and every time a new page is loaded I want the user to show that his request is being processed, so even if the request takes a couple of seconds, the user won't get nervous because he knows that something is happening.

I would really appreciate any help for finding a solution, because I can't seem to find any...

Comment: Can you make all the data requests as ajax-calls that are separate to the rest of the page-load. This way the main page is always "p[resent" and only the page-content gets reloaded slowly. It also means you can then use a loader-icon on every fetch of the page-content, because you can guarantee that you';ll have the rest of the page-layout there with js etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a javascript animation to show to the user that something is happening.

For example : http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/

Comment: So, I either need to change all links and buttons to work with AJAX or integrate Turbolinks in my application? Because I thought there would be a solution without AJAX...

Comment: As you want. Your goal is to track the % of loading and to update your progression bar according to it.